# make a condition in twig

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig

I was wondering if it is possible in Twig to create a condition and if that's true or false then change some html for Bootstrap 3 purpose.

Let's say I have a div container with 5 columns in it. In the last column there's a Facebook widget. When I choose to hide the widget then the container only has 4 columns instead of 5. 
Is it possible to setup a condition that automatically changes the html to 4 columns?

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
{% if hide_fb_widget %}<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... Facebook widget ...</div>{% endif %}
```

As you can see when the fb widget is hidden the "col-md-2" needs to be changed to:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
```

Is there a simple way to do this? I'm pretty new to Twig...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the class that can change ( `col-md-2` / `col-md-3` ) on Twig variables.

```
{% if hide_fb_widget %}
  {% set width_class = 'col-md-3' %}
{% else %}
  {% set width_class = 'col-md-2' %}
{% endif %}
```

Then, you're using your variable instead of raw strings.

```
<div class="{{ width_class }} col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="{{ width_class }} col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="{{ width_class }} col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
<div class="{{ width_class }} col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... some content ...</div>
{% if hide_fb_widget %}<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">... Facebook widget ...</div>{% endif %}
```